# Representations of $SU(2)$ and the complex subspace of its weight spaces

Tags: representation-theory

I'm following these notes on [Representation Theory and Quantum Mechanics by Noah Miller](https://scholar.harvard.edu/files/noahmiller/files/representation-theory-quantum.pdf). In chapter 12, the author is classifying all of the irreducible representations of $SU(2)$, and I'm running into some confusion with a particular claim that's made. I'll quote it here and point out my confusion,

> Say that $\pi: SU(2) \rightarrow GL(V)$ is a finite dimensional irreducible representation of $SU(2)$ where $V$ is a complex vector space. There will be a highest weight vector $v_{k_H} \in V$. I claim that the following subspace $W \in V$ is closed under the action of all Lie algebra representation elements $\pi'(X)$:
> $$W \equiv \mathrm{span}_{\mathbb{C}}\big\{v_{k_H}, \pi'(S_-) v_{k_H}, \pi'(S_-)^2v_{k_H}, \pi'(S_-)^3 v_{k_H},...\big\}$$
> (By "closed" I mean that for all $w \in W$ and $X \in \mathfrak{su}(2)$, we have $\pi'(X)w \in W$.)

As for the notation here, the skew-adjoint generators of $SU(2)$ have been defined as $X_1, X_2, X_3$, where as the self-adjoint matrices $S_j \in \mathfrak{su}(2)_\mathbb{C}$ are defined as,
$$S_j \equiv i X_j$$

Now the proof of this subspace $W$ being closed begins like so,

> **Proof**: As $W$ is a complex vector space, all vectors $w \in W$ and Lie algebra representation elements $\pi'(X)$ satisfy $\pi'(X)w \in W$ if and only if $i \pi'(X) w \in W$. Therefore, if we show that $W$ is closed under the action of the complexified Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(2)_{\mathbb{C}}$, we are done.

I don't understand this argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $W$ is a complex vector space, for any $w\in W$, $zw \in W$ where $z \in \mathbb{C}$. This is as per the definition of a complex vector space, that it be closed under multiplication by complex scalars such as $z$. An example of this would be the fact that $iw \in W$. Suppose then we define $w' = iw$, and make the claim in the opposite direction, that if $iw = w' \in W$ then this implies that $w\in W$ also. Well this is simply another multiplication by a complex scalar, namely by $-i$. See that $-i(w') = -i(iw) = w$ and so we must conclude that $w \in W$.

Let's repeat this but define $w' = \pi'(X)w$. Then by the same logic, if we can show that $iw' = i\pi'(X)w \in W$ for all $X$ and $w$, then by definition we will have shown that all $w' = \pi'(X)w \in W$ as well. So it's just a matter of demonstrating that $W$ is closed on the complexified representation of the $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ Lie algebra, all the $i\pi'(X)$, and we'll have implicitly shown that it's closed under all $\pi'(x)$.